# RecordStore name change and null value in .db file in J2ME

Tags: java-me, rms, midp-2.0

In my application, I create the RecordStore named as a "UserData", but when I run the emulator, the database saved in the appdb folder named as a "00000003-User-Data.db", and when I open this file,there is a lots of null value with every single record.

What is the solution for saving the db file same as a RecordStore name and how can I remove null value from db file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not bother about the file name of the RecordStore. It is not available to MIDP apps on devices.

Comment: So how can I store my database and fetch data from it through MIDP apps?

Comment: you need to write it in to a RecordStore, and then read it in again.  This must be done using the RecordStore APIs.